# Tool for comparing sets of folders, their names, and their contents in order to identify differences?

Tags: directory, editor

Trying to identify differences between two project folders that in theory should be identical or close to identical.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your working on *nix. I wrote this simple bash script years ago and it does the job pretty simply.  Diffs the files you specify with what's in another directory location.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# this script compares specified files in the default dir against a target directory
#
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: diffDir target_dir files ..."
        echo -en "Does a parallel diff of one or more files against versions in the target_dir
e.g. diffDir /home/mydir/version1  *.c\n"
        exit 1;
fi

dir=$1;
shift
files=$@

echo "Diffing files in default dir with those in target_dir $dir"
echo "<left : files in default dir"
echo "right> : files in target_dir"

for file in $files; do
        echo "==================================="
        echo "Diffing:  $file "
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
           echo " ... Skipping, directory"
           continue
        fi
        sdiff -s $file $dir/$file
        echo " "
done
```